# How to reverse engineer a Gitlab URL to point to a certain code line number in a Merge Request

Tags: url, hash, gitlab, sha, gitlab-api

In order to connect a test management tool with GitLab, I would like to display a URL link in the test management tool in order to create a comment for a certain code line in a MR in Gitlab.

I checked the official GitLab API documentation but did not find the explanation how the URLs are being created in GitLab.

The Script which would build the final URL has the following information:

- Merge request path
- File to be commented
- Code line(s) of file to be commented

The idea is: the user can click on the link, on a new browser tab a GitLab page opens, where the form for a Code comment in the correct MR is already opened and point to the correct code line(s).

I analysed how the URL in GitLab changes if I navigate through the merge request page.
My observations:

1. The generic URL for a MR looks like this: https://git.company.com/project/group/repository/-/merge_requests/merge_request_iid/
2. If I navigate to the "Changes" tab, the URL changes to:
   https://git.company.com/project/group/repository/-/merge_requests/merge_request_iid/diffs
3. If I click on a file in the Changes tab, the URL gets extended by a hash:
   https://git.company.com/project/group/repository/-/merge_requests/merge_request_iid/diffs#diff-content-00fcae07ce917a6336e839f6582227ddfc5ed59e
4. A code line can be referenced in the end with *line-version-1_line-version-2*:
   https://git.company.com/project/group/repository/-/merge_requests/merge_request_iid/diffs#diff-content-00fcae07ce917a6336e839f6582227ddfc5ed59e_27_27

This is exactly what I need, now the tricky part. How to get the hash value? All other information I already have as input parameters into my script. I checked the API docs for "Commit", "diff versions", "notes" and "visual review discussions" and also queried the API with multiple requests. But none of these chapters describe how the hash value can be queried via the API.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution to my question:
in this MR you will find the explanation how the hash value is calculated:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/merge_requests/7298

> #hash_lineA_lineB, where the hash is a sha1 encoded file's path, and lineA and lineB are line numbers of exact changes presented in file. Example:  "....../diffs#d84b028799a0d15b64d62a1d547297b47bc4b58e_43_43"

So I only need to hash the path to the changed file with sha1 and append the line of code which I want to open with the URL.

Answer (score 1):

That hash is not from the Git commit :-(

> How to get the hash value?

It's possible that this is the [one GraphQL component](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/reference/#diffpositioninput) in this context: `diffPositionInput`.

Maybe searching the code for `diff-content` leads further. Please check these files for example. Esp the `javascripts/diffs/components` ones seem relevant:

```
$ rg --glob='*.{js,vue,rb}' --count 'diff-content' | sort --field-separator=: --key=2n
app/assets/javascripts/deprecated_notes.js:1
app/assets/javascripts/diffs/components/app.vue:1
app/assets/javascripts/diffs/components/diff_content.vue:1
app/assets/javascripts/diffs/components/diff_file_header.vue:1
app/assets/javascripts/diffs/store/actions.js:1
app/assets/javascripts/main.js:1
app/assets/javascripts/merge_conflicts/merge_conflict_resolver_app.vue:1
app/assets/javascripts/notes/components/diff_with_note.vue:1
app/assets/javascripts/vue_shared/components/markdown/suggestion_diff_row.vue:1
app/assets/javascripts/vue_shared/components/notes/system_note.vue:1
spec/features/issues/create_issue_for_single_discussion_in_merge_request_spec.rb:1
spec/features/merge_request/user_reviews_image_spec.rb:1
spec/features/merge_request/user_scrolls_to_note_on_load_spec.rb:1
spec/frontend/diffs/components/diff_file_spec.js:1
spec/frontend/tracking/tracking_spec.js:1
app/assets/javascripts/single_file_diff.js:2
spec/features/expand_collapse_diffs_spec.rb:2
spec/features/merge_request/user_creates_image_diff_notes_spec.rb:2
spec/frontend/diffs/components/diff_file_header_spec.js:2
spec/frontend/vue_shared/components/markdown/suggestion_diff_row_spec.js:2
spec/frontend/notes/components/diff_with_note_spec.js:3
spec/frontend/single_file_diff_spec.js:3
app/assets/javascripts/diffs/components/diff_file.vue:4
spec/features/merge_request/user_resolves_diff_notes_and_discussions_resolve_spec.rb:26
```